# Boostrap 3 - Change css background image javascript

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I am using a modal with a contact form on my Bootstrap 3 web page, I would like the modal background image to change when the form is submitted.

I have implemented the modal-content image using this class in my custom css:

```
.modal-content {
    max-height: 370px;
    background-image: url('../images/img_before_submit.png');
}
```

I have been trying to change the .modal-content background image in my form submit ajax script using the following statement:

```
$('.modal-content').css('background-image', 'url(../images/img_after_submit.png)');
```

This does not work, how can I change the modal background image?

Comment: that line of code works: http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/214/. are there any errors in the console?

Comment: You are right, it just don not work inside of my ajax code!

Comment: can we see all relevant code?